# Code first migrations update database lose data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

How do you update a database without losing data with `Code First`?
I'm working on a new project and I already did some changes to the database in the code. And then it just hits me, `migrations` seems to always drop and recreate whatever you changed.

This is something I don't want to happen when I go live with the application.

Comment: I would NOT recommend using code first migrations to update production databases.  Find a different way to keep track of structural changes and create ALTER scripts.  You need to have more control over changes than a SQL-gen tool gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Script option, to generate scrpit. i change it to alter table when it tries to drop it:

```
Update-Database -Script -ProjectName Proj -StartupProjectName Proj
```